# Using specific controller in layout - CakePHP

Tags: oop, cakephp

I'm newbie in CakePHP and I have a few questions.

I'm trying to set up my first CakePHP website, and I want to display menu with links in my layout. I've created model called MenuItem, then I've created controller "MenuItemsController" and then a function show. When I access /menuitems/show/ all my links are displayed. So here's the problem. I want do call this controller in my layout so links will be visible on every subpage. First question is how to call this controller, and second how will output look like ? Do I have to create view for this cotroller if I don't want to use /menuitems/show/ or it's okay to set controller to output just array of data ?

Thank you!

Comment: Provide an example of what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
First question is how to call this controller, and second how will output look like ?
```

Use [requestAction()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller%3a%3arequestAction) to request the data from the view OR better, set it based on the page you're on in your AppController::beforeFfilter() method.

In your layout simply use [an element](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#elements) $this->element('menu'); and use the set data in it or, if you go for [requestAction() do this call inside the element](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#passing-variables-into-an-element), you can even cache the element.

Read the links to the CakePHP book in the text, the book contains example code as well.